# Using pretrained VGG-16 to get a feature vector from an image

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, vgg-net

I want to get a feature vector out of an image by passing the image through a pre-trained VGG-16. I used the pretrained Resnet50 to get a feature vector and that worked perfectly. But when I use the same method to get a feature vector from the VGG-16 network, I don’t get the 4096-d vector which I assume I should get. I got the code from a variety of sources and it is as follows:

```
vgg16_model=models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
modules=list(vgg16_model.children())[:-1]
vgg16_model=nn.Sequential(*modules)

data=moveaxis(data,2,0)
img_var=Variable(torch.from_numpy(data).unsqueeze(0)).float()
features_var=vgg16_model(img_var)
features=features_var.data
features=features.data.numpy()
print(features.shape)
```

The variable `“data”` is an image numpy array of dimensions `(300, 400, 3)`
Hence I use the move axis to jumble the axis so that I have 3 channels and not 300.
The output(`features.shape`) which I get is : `(1, 512, 7, 7)`
I want a 4096-d vector as the VGG-16 gives before the softmax layer.
I even tried the `list(vgg16_model.classifier.children())[:-1]` approach but that did not go too well either. There are a lot of discussions about this but none of them worked for me. Let me know where I might be going wrong. Thank you!